# mkdir missing from MSYS

Tags: mingw, msys

Why do I get this in MSYS?

```
user@lappy1 ~
$ mkdir test
sh: mkdir: command not found
```

Basic commands like cd and pwd work just fine.  What happened to mkdir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like your `$PATH` is not set up properly, or your startup sequence is broken. what's the result of `echo $PATH`? there should be something like `.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin` in the beginning. `mkdir` should be in `/bin`, so if you have `/bin` in the `PATH`, it should work. if there is no `mkdir` in `/bin`, check your installation. the `PATH` is initialized from `/etc/profile` - look if there is something like `export PATH=...` in it. `/etc/profile` is read when bash is invoked as login shell, so also check if bash is started with the `--login` (`-l`) option (this usually happens from `msys.bat`). last, `cd` and `pwd` are *shell builtin commands*, so they work in the shell regardless of any `PATH` setting.

Comment: Good tip.  I have a mkdir.exe in /bin and /bin is in my path.  Here's the weird part:  I have a mkdir directory in /bin!!!  I renamed the directory to mkdir.bad.  Now, mkdir works again.  I have no idea how that happened, but it works now!